# Show DIV in embedded DIV on HTML select using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a page where people trigger a questionaire by selecting START in a webform - it pops open the DIV for the 1st question.

As they answer each question (yes/no choices) it either opens a DIV specific to that question which says "NO - GO AWAY because XXXX" or brings up the next question in a new DIV... this repeats about 8 times.

So far, I can get the FIRST Question to appear, but it won't do anything when I select an answer for question1 - it SHOULD make Q2 DIV appear or provide the context DIV for why they can't proceed.

I've got a (very) stripped down demo in [this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7rsLvcde/)

The HTML code is:

```
  <div class="container">
      <form id="GeneralEnquiryForm" class="row justify-content-center no-gutters col-12" name="GeneralEnquiry" method="post" action="https://somesite.com/forms/accessrequest/request_submitted.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
          <div id="GeneralEnquiryHeading">
                    <h2>Request Form</h2>
                </div>
          </div>

        <!-- ############################ -->
        <!-- # Main Menu Selection Tree # -->
        <!-- ############################ -->

        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <label for="requestSelect">This checklist MUST be complete to submit this form. *</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="requestSelect" id="requestSelect" required>
                            <option value="" selected disabled="disabled">Please select the check to begin.</option>
                            <option title="Option 1" value="HealthCheck">Commence Checklist</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ############################# -->
                    <!-- #    Health Check                   # -->
                    <!-- ############################# -->
                    <div class="form-group col-12 clearAll HealthCheck fade show" role="dialog">
                        <div>
                            <h6>Request Form</h6>
                            <h2>CHECK LIST</h2>
                        </div>

            <label for="HealthCheck1">Have you returned from overseas travel in the past 14 days? *</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="HealthCheck1" id="HealthCheck1" required>
                                <option value="" selected disabled="disabled"> Please select Yes or No </option>
                                <option title="HealthCheck1Yes" value="HealthCheck1Yes">Yes</option>
                                <option title="HealthCheck1No" value="HealthCheck1No">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-12 clearAll HealthCheck1No alert alert-info fade show" role="alert">
                        <label for="HealthCheck2">Have you returned from interstate travel in the past 14 days? *</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="HealthCheck2" id="HealthCheck2" required>
                            <option value="" selected disabled="disabled"> Please select Yes or No </option>
                            <option title="HealthCheck2Yes" value="HealthCheck2Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option title="HealthCheck2No" value="HealthCheck2No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-12 clearAll HealthCheck2No alert alert-info fade show" role="alert">
                        <label for="HealthCheck3">Are you currently required to self-isolate? *</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="HealthCheck3" id="HealthCheck3" required>
                            <option value="" selected disabled="disabled"> Please select Yes or No </option>
                            <option title="HealthCheck3Yes" value="HealthCheck3Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option title="HealthCheck3No" value="HealthCheck3No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                    <!-- ############################ -->
                    <!-- # Health Check Pop-Up Help # -->
                    <!-- ############################ -->

                    <div class="form-group col-12 clearAll HealthCheck1Yes alert alert-warning fade show" role="alert">
                        <h5>Do <strong>NoT</strong> attend campus!</h5>
                        <div class="row col-12 align-items-center">
                            <div class="termsIcon col-2 .col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                                <img src="../images/warning_small.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <h6><strong>If you have returned from overseas travel in the past 14 days, you should be self-isolating.</strong></h6></br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-12 clearAll HealthCheck2Yes alert alert-warning fade show" role="alert">
                        <h5>Do <strong>NoT</strong> attend campus!</h5>
                        <div class="row col-12 align-items-center">
                            <div class="termsIcon col-2 .col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                                <img src="../images/warning_small.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <h6><strong>If you have returned from interstate travel in the past 14 days, you should be self-isolating</strong></h6></br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </br></br>
                    </div>

        <!-- ############################# -->
        <!-- # Individual Pop-Up Modules # -->
        <!-- ############################# -->

          <hr class="separator col-12">
          * Please fill in ALL of the above fields or the form will not submit.
          <hr class="separator col-12">
            <div id="new-div"></div>

          <div class="form-group justify-content-right col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="return checkform()">Submit Request</button>
          </div>
      </form>


            </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.js"></script>


    <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#requestSelect").change(function() {
          var val = $(this).val();
          if(val === "HealthCheck") {
            $(".clearAll").hide();
            $(".HealthCheck").show();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

    <script>
                $(function () {
                $("#HealthCheck1").change(function() {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    if(val === "HealthCheck1Yes") {
                        $(".HealthCheck1Yes").show();
                    }
                    else if(val === "HealthCheck1No") {
                        $(".HealthCheck1No").show();
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```

[Edit - Fixed JSFiddle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed closing your function at the end `})`:

```
$("#HealthCheck1").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "HealthCheck1Yes") {
        $(".HealthCheck1Yes").show();
    }
    else if(val === "HealthCheck1No") {
        $(".HealthCheck1No").show();
    }
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7ewd6q9/)

There are a few other recommendations to consider for you:

1. Use the proper syntax of self-closing HTML tags. Use `<br />`instead of `</br>`.
2. Use proper indentation (for all documents) it helps you find not closed functions and other errors more quickly.
3. Put your javascript into a proper file and include it afterwards with `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`. This will allow your code editor (like intellij) to detect simple closing tag/function problems.

Comment: ok - Fixed the <br /> tags

Also fixed the missing ) at the end of the function...


Sadly - it's still not working.   My DIV's are remaining hidden...  :(

Comment: Check my updated answer that includes a working jsfiddle example